# Javascript Tic-Tac-Toe, Why is it waiting to alert a user after the entire board has been filled?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I know that there has already been numerous questions regarding Tic-Tac-Toe javascript, however, my question is different. I have the code running, but it wont declare if there is a winner or if it's a cat's game unless the ENTIRE board is filled. I have a feeling that it's my `if` statements and that it cannot read a "nodeValue of null" until the entire board is not null. Question is, how do i fix this problem? I have already tried giving the board a "blank" text node, however, that means the "blank" squares are equal to each other. Is there any way I can still compare empty squares with filled squares to get a win? (Im specifically referring to the Array defined in the `start_game()` function and the `if` statements inside the `beat_game()` function which compare the 2-D arrays) Also, in addition to this answer, I am open to ANY suggestion about my js that could be improved. Here is the code itself:

```
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function page_load() {
       // alert('in here');
            start_game();
        }

        function start_game() {
           if (document.getElementById('board')) {
                document.getElementById('board').parentNode.removeChild(document.getElementById('board'));
            }
            win_Array = [
                [
                    'TL',
                    'TM',
                    'TR'
                ],
                [
                    'ML',
                    'MM',
                    'MR'
                ],
                [
                    'BL',
                    'BM',
                    'BR'
                ]
            ];
            body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
            table = document.createElement('table');
            table.id = 'board';
            table.setAttribute('border', '1');
            body.appendChild(table);
            tbody = document.createElement('tbody');
            table.appendChild(tbody);
            run = 0;
            win = 0;
            var count;
            td_Array = [{
                t: 'TL',
                m: 'ML',
                b: 'BL'
            }, {
                t: 'TM',
                m: 'MM',
                b: 'BM'
            }, {
                t: 'TR',
                m: 'MR',
                b: 'BR'
            }];
            tr = document.createElement('tr');
            tr.id = "tr1";
            tbody.appendChild(tr);
            for (count = 0; count <= 2; count++) {
                td = document.createElement('td');
                td.id = td_Array[count].t;
                td.setAttribute('onClick', 'value("' + td_Array[count].t + '")');
                tr.appendChild(td);
            }
            tr = document.createElement('tr');
            tr.id = "tr2";
            tbody.appendChild(tr);
            for (count = 0; count <= 2; count++) {
                td = document.createElement('td');
                td.id = td_Array[count].m;
                td.setAttribute('onClick', 'value("' + td_Array[count].m + '")');
                tr.appendChild(td);
            }
            tr = document.createElement('tr');
            tr.id = "tr3";
            tbody.appendChild(tr);
            for (count = 0; count <= 2; count++) {
                td = document.createElement('td');
                td.id = td_Array[count].b;
                td.setAttribute('onClick', 'value("' + td_Array[count].b + '")');
                tr.appendChild(td);
            }
        }

        function value(data) {
            console.log(data);
            console.log(document.getElementById(data));
            if (run % 2 !== 0) {
                td = document.getElementById(data);
                text = document.createTextNode('O');
                td.appendChild(text);
                document.getElementById(data).removeAttribute('onClick');
            } else {
                td = document.getElementById(data);
                text = document.createTextNode('X');
                td.appendChild(text);
                document.getElementById(data).removeAttribute('onClick');
            } //document.getElementById('').childNodes[0].nodeValue //node value prevents error.
            run++;
                beat_game();
        }

        function beat_game() {
           // alert('test sucessful');
            var x, y;

                for (x = 0; x < 3; x++) 
                { //for checking across td's
                   if (document.getElementById(win_Array[x][0]).childNodes[0].nodeValue == document.getElementById(win_Array[x][1]).childNodes[0].nodeValue 
                   && document.getElementById(win_Array[x][1]).childNodes[0].nodeValue == document.getElementById(win_Array[x][2]).childNodes[0].nodeValue) 
                    {
                        win = true;
                        win_value = document.getElementById(win_Array[x][0]).childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                    } 
                }
                for (y = 0; y < 3; y++) 
                { //for checking down td's
                    if (document.getElementById(win_Array[0][y]).childNodes[0].nodeValue == document.getElementById(win_Array[1][y]).childNodes[0].nodeValue
                    && document.getElementById(win_Array[1][y]).childNodes[0].nodeValue == document.getElementById(win_Array[2][y]).childNodes[0].nodeValue)
                    {
                        win = true;
                        win_value = document.getElementById(win_Array[0][y]).childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                    }
                } // checking across values here...
                    if ( document.getElementById(win_Array[0][0]).childNodes[0].nodeValue == document.getElementById(win_Array[1][1]).childNodes[0].nodeValue
                    && document.getElementById(win_Array[1][1]).childNodes[0].nodeValue == document.getElementById(win_Array[2][2]).childNodes[0].nodeValue
                    || document.getElementById(win_Array[0][2]).childNodes[0].nodeValue == document.getElementById(win_Array[1][1]).childNodes[0].nodeValue
                    && document.getElementById(win_Array[1][1]).childNodes[0].nodeValue == document.getElementById(win_Array[2][0]).childNodes[0].nodeValue)
                    {
                        win = true;
                        win_value = document.getElementById(win_Array[0][0]).childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                    }
                    if(win == true)
                    {
                        if(win_value == 'X')
                        {
                            alert('Player 1 Wins!');
                        }else{
                            alert('Player 2 Wins!');
                        }
                    }else {
                        alert("Cat's Game!");
                    }
        } 
    </script>
    <style>
        td {
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        body {
            font-size: 6;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Thanks Again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right that the issue is in your `beat_game()` function.

An exception will get thrown upon the first condition because there is no child node in the td cell (for example `document.getElementById(win_Array[x][0]).childNodes[0]`) which you attempt to grab the `nodeValue` attribute from.

To fix this, you can use a safer/universal way of grabbing the cell's value for how you've built the stage by using innerHTML:
`document.getElementById(win_Array[x][0]).innerHTML`

To solve the issue that all blank squares are equal to each other, you can add an additional check to ensure that the cell actually contains a value before saying `win = true`. Combining all these tips, one of the loops will look this this:

```
for (x = 0; x < 3; x++) 
    { //for checking across td's
    if (document.getElementById(win_Array[x][0]).innerHTML == document.getElementById(win_Array[x][1]).innerHTML 
    && document.getElementById(win_Array[x][1]).innerHTML == document.getElementById(win_Array[x][2]).innerHTML) 
     {
          win_value = document.getElementById(win_Array[x][0]).innerHTML;
          win = win_value ? true : false;
     } 
}
```

After you've done this, you'll notice a new bug, where the game will constantly alert "Cat's game!". Because after the game winning checks, if win is not true, we will always fall to the else case. To fix this, I suggest utilizing your `run` variable to determine when the max number of moves has been performed.

Another bug is your last condition to check for diagonals in the game. You assign the win_value to always be the top left of the board, but the actual win value can vary in this case since you've combined both diagonal cases in one statement.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Debugging the script, I see an issue with the following line (and all other similar variants):

```
 document.getElementById(win_Array[x][0]).childNodes[0].nodeValue == document.getElementById(win_Array[x][1]).childNodes[0].nodeValue
```

You have to be aware that childNodes[0] is not always going to be defined - in first run, your table is not going to have any table cells with child nodes. When you insert an X or an O, that is a child node of the table cell. When there is no X or O, there is no child node, and there will be an error every time you make the move. That is why the game requires completion to determine a winner.

I would suggest to have a separate 3x3 array (in JS it's array of arrays) of strings or numbers and use that data structure to check for winning conditions.

Comment: Do you mean, assigning each box a numerical value and add those values up to make an answer equal to another answer in a separate array?

Comment: That is another way to do it - create an array of size 9 (3x3) and index each box, and determine the winning conditions based on that.